# Javascript console error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onloadedmetadata' of null

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5-audio

I have tried to stylise the html5 audio player using this [codepen](https://jsfiddle.net/cz4a2L03/2/). The codepen works exactly as i want to but when i include the javascript and html in the page below I get this error. What am I doing wrong?

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onloadedmetadata' of null

I don't understand why it works in the codepen but not on my website?

HTML code:

```
<div class="filters">

  <div class="ui-group">
    <div class="button-group js-radio-button-group" data-filter-group="color">
      <button class="button filter-all-button" data-filter="">Filter by: all</button>  
        <?php $categories = get_categories();
foreach($categories as $category) { ?>
        <button class="button filter-category" data-filter=".<?php echo $category->slug; ?>" id="button"><?php echo $category->cat_name ?></button>
<?php } ?>
    </div>
  </div>

  

</div>

<div class="grid">
    
    
    <?php $posts = get_posts( 
        array(
            'post_type' => 'post', 
            'posts_per_page' => -1
        )
    );


foreach ( $posts as $post ) { 
    $audio = get_field('file', $post->ID);
     $categories = get_the_category($post->ID);   
 ?>
    

     <div class="audio-box <?php foreach ( $categories as $category ) { ?> <?php echo esc_attr($category->slug).' '; ?><?php } ?> ">

      <div class="audio-btn">
          <img src="https://some-image.jpg" alt="play"/>
      </div>
      <div class="audio-content">
        <div class="date">Published 18/01/20</div>
        <h2><?php echo get_the_title( $post->ID ); ?></h2>
        <p><?php echo get_the_excerpt($post->ID); ?></p>
      </div>
      <div style="clear:both;"></div>
      <div class="audio-player play-wrap">
        <audio id="player audio" class="music">
    <source src="<?php echo $audio['url']; ?>" type="audio/mpeg" />
</audio>

<div id="audio-player">
    <div id="controls">
        <i id="play" class="fa fa-play"></i>
        <div id="progressbar"></div>
        <span id="time" class="time">00:00</span>
       <i id="mute" class="fa fa-volume-up"></i>
        <div id="volume"></div>    
    </div>
  
</div>
          <i class="fa fa-play play"></i>
                        
      </div>
         
         


      
  </div>

    
 <?php   }


?>
  
  
</div>
```

Javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    
    
    
    
    var audio_player = $("#audio-player");
var play_button = $('#play');
var progress_bar = $("#progressbar");
var time = $("#time");
var mute_button = $('#mute');
var volume_bar = $('#volume');
var more_info = $('#more-info-box');
var info_tray = $("#info-tray");
var player = document.getElementById('player');
var duration = 0;
var volume = 0.75;

player.onloadedmetadata = function() {
  duration = player.duration;
  progress_bar.progressbar("option", {
    'max': duration
  });
};

player.load();
player.volume = 0.75;
player.addEventListener("timeupdate", function() {
  progress_bar.progressbar('value', player.currentTime);
  time.text(getTime(player.currentTime));
}, false);

function getTime(t) {
  var m = ~~(t / 60),
    s = ~~(t % 60);
  return (m < 10 ? "0" + m : m) + ':' + (s < 10 ? "0" + s : s);
}

function getProgressBarClickInfo(progress_bar, e) {
  var offset = progress_bar.position();
  var x = e.pageX - offset.left; // or e.offsetX (less support, though)
  var y = e.pageY - offset.top; // or e.offsetY
  var max = progress_bar.progressbar("option", "max");
  var value = x * max / progress_bar.width();

  return {
    x: x,
    y: y,
    max: max,
    value: value
  };
}

volume_bar.progressbar({
  value: player.volume * 100,
});

volume_bar.click(function(e) {
  var info = getProgressBarClickInfo($(this), e);
  volume_bar.progressbar('value', info.value);
  player.volume = info.value / info.max;
});

progress_bar.progressbar({
  value: player.currentTime,
});

progress_bar.click(function(e) {
  var info = getProgressBarClickInfo($(this), e);
  player.currentTime = player.duration / info.max * info.value;
});

play_button.click(function() {
  player[player.paused ? 'play' : 'pause']();
  $(this).toggleClass("fa-pause", !player.paused);
  $(this).toggleClass("fa-play", player.paused);
});

mute_button.click(function() {
  if (player.volume == 0) {
    player.volume = volume;
  } else {
    volume = player.volume;
    player.volume = 0;
  }

  volume_bar.progressbar('value', player.volume * 100);

  $(this).toggleClass("fa-volume-up", player.volume != 0);
  $(this).toggleClass("fa-volume-off", player.volume == 0);
});

more_info.click(function() {
  audio_player.animate({
    height: (audio_player.height() == 50) ? 100 : 50
  }, 1000);
});




</script>
```

Comment: `player` is undefined ... is that code run before the element exists?

Comment: @JaromandaX the javascript is run below the audio player html code.

Comment: oh, I see the issue - there's no element with `id="player"`

Comment: There is, the audio element has the id <audio id="player audio" class="music">

Comment: The `id` attribute doesn't work like the class one; you need `id="player"` for your JS code to work. (assigning multiple ids to an element doesn't make sense because an id is supposed to be unique)

Comment: notice where I put my `"` and the single word inside them

Answer (score 0):

JS can't find id `player` in the included html. That's why it is throwing that error Problem is in HTML. Please read [html id naming convention](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) for more information

```
<div class="filters">

  <div class="ui-group">
    <div class="button-group js-radio-button-group" data-filter-group="color">
      <button class="button filter-all-button" data-filter="">Filter by: all</button>  
        <?php $categories = get_categories();
foreach($categories as $category) { ?>
        <button class="button filter-category" data-filter=".<?php echo $category->slug; ?>" id="button"><?php echo $category->cat_name ?></button>
<?php } ?>
    </div>
  </div>

  

</div>

<div class="grid">
    
    
    <?php $posts = get_posts( 
        array(
            'post_type' => 'post', 
            'posts_per_page' => -1
        )
    );


foreach ( $posts as $post ) { 
    $audio = get_field('file', $post->ID);
     $categories = get_the_category($post->ID);   
 ?>
    

     <div class="audio-box <?php foreach ( $categories as $category ) { ?> <?php echo esc_attr($category->slug).' '; ?><?php } ?> ">

      <div class="audio-btn">
          <img src="https://some-image.jpg" alt="play"/>
      </div>
      <div class="audio-content">
        <div class="date">Published 18/01/20</div>
        <h2><?php echo get_the_title( $post->ID ); ?></h2>
        <p><?php echo get_the_excerpt($post->ID); ?></p>
      </div>
      <div style="clear:both;"></div>
      <div class="audio-player play-wrap">
        <audio id="player" class="music"> <!-- Problem was here -->
    <source src="<?php echo $audio['url']; ?>" type="audio/mpeg" />
</audio>

<div id="audio-player">
    <div id="controls">
        <i id="play" class="fa fa-play"></i>
        <div id="progressbar"></div>
        <span id="time" class="time">00:00</span>
       <i id="mute" class="fa fa-volume-up"></i>
        <div id="volume"></div>    
    </div>
  
</div>
          <i class="fa fa-play play"></i>
                        
      </div>
         
         


      
  </div>
```